# Entity relationship design - Converting diagram to database tables in one-to-many relationship

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, database-schema, entityset

I have a database entity relationship diagram with the following entities and their attributes:

```
Flight:
Date (primary key)
Num_available_seats

Reservation:
CustomerName
CustomerPhone

Seat:
SeatNumber (primary key)
```

Reservation is the middle ground relationship between the `Flight` and the `Seat`. There is a one-to-many relationship between `Seat` and `Flight` (namely, one `Flight` can have many `Seat`s by way of `Reservation`).

When breaking down these relationships into tables, because this is a one-to-many relationship, I know that `Seat` can consume `Reservation` so that there doesn't need to be a specific `Reservation` table in the database.

However, my question is this... In the table for `Seat`, I know to put the primary keys of `Seat` and `Flight` (`SeatNumber` and `Date`), but do I also include the non-primary attributes of the `Reservation` relationship?

Here are my two options I'm toying around with:

```
Seat(SeatNumber, Date)
Seat(SeatNumber, Date, CustomerName, CustomerPhone)
```

Which one is correct? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Anyone? Any help is greatly appreciated... I know the answer is right under my nose, I just don't know which table is correct from an entity relationship design perspective.

Answer (score 1):

To enhance data integrity I will suggest a little more constraints:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, given that Reservation actually has business data (client info for instance), the Reservation table should consume Seat.

Like this:

```
Flight:
Date (primary key) 
Num_available_seats

Reservation:
CustomerName
CustomerPhone
SeatNumber
Date (FK from Flight)
```

scraping the Seat table.

Also, if possible, I would rework the Flight table a little bit:

```
Flight:
FlightId (PK)
Date
AirplaneId (this could be a FK from some Airplane table, if it exists, or simply an identifier for the airplane that makes the flight)
Num_available_seats
```

This would modify your Reservation tale like this:

```
Reservation:
CustomerName
CustomerPhone
FlightId (FK)
SeatNumber
```

I hope this helps.